# group_left not working as expected in promql

Tags: prometheus, promql

Here is the results of kube_deployment_labels:

```
kube_deployment_labels{deployment="nginx-deploy",endpoint="http",instance="10.73.10.219:8080",job="kube-state-metrics",label_app="nginx-deploy",label_test_com_team="neon",namespace="default",pod="kube-prometheus-stack-kube-state-metrics-857d997b65-m7jf9",service="kube-prometheus-stack-kube-state-metrics"} | 1
-- | --
kube_deployment_labels{deployment="nginx-deploy-new",endpoint="http",instance="10.73.10.219:8080",job="kube-state-metrics",label_app="nginx-deploy-new",label_test_com_team="neon",namespace="default",pod="kube-prometheus-stack-kube-state-metrics-857d997b65-m7jf9",service="kube-prometheus-stack-kube-state-metrics"}
```

And results of the below expression:

```
(kube_deployment_spec_replicas{job="kube-state-metrics",namespace=~".*"}
  != kube_deployment_status_replicas_available{job="kube-state-metrics",namespace=~".*"})
  and (changes(kube_deployment_status_replicas_updated{job="kube-state-metrics",namespace=~".*"}[5m])
  == 0)

kube_deployment_labels{deployment="nginx-deploy",endpoint="http",instance="10.73.10.219:8080",job="kube-state-metrics",label_app="nginx-deploy",label_test_com_team="neon",namespace="default",pod="kube-prometheus-stack-kube-state-metrics-857d997b65-m7jf9",service="kube-prometheus-stack-kube-state-metrics"} | 1
-- | --
kube_deployment_labels{deployment="nginx-deploy-new",endpoint="http",instance="10.73.10.219:8080",job="kube-state-metrics",label_app="nginx-deploy-new",label_test_com_team="neon",namespace="default",pod="kube-prometheus-stack-kube-state-metrics-857d997b65-m7jf9",service="kube-prometheus-stack-kube-state-metrics"}
```

But when I try to combine both,

```
(kube_deployment_spec_replicas{job="kube-state-metrics",namespace=~".*"}
  != kube_deployment_status_replicas_available{job="kube-state-metrics",namespace=~".*"})
  and (changes(kube_deployment_status_replicas_updated{job="kube-state-metrics",namespace=~".*"}[5m])
  == 0) * on (deployment,namespace) group_left(label_team_com_team) kube_deployment_labels
```

The results show only the metrics which do not have label "label_test_com_team"

Answer (score 1):

This has worked for me,

```
(kube_deployment_spec_replicas{job="kube-state-metrics",namespace=~".*"} * on (deployment,namespace) group_left(label_axway_com_team) kube_deployment_labels
  != kube_deployment_status_replicas_available{job="kube-state-metrics",namespace=~".*"}* on (deployment,namespace) group_left(label_axway_com_team) kube_deployment_labels)
  and (changes(kube_deployment_status_replicas_updated{job="kube-state-metrics",namespace=~".*"}[5m])
  == 0)* on (deployment,namespace) group_left(label_axway_com_team) kube_deployment_labels
```